# Cant find out why this part of my code crash in C

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm sure it's very simple, but I cant seem to find why my code crashes.  This is the beginning of my program and it already crashes.  It is finding prime numbers using the sieve of eratosthenes (or partly).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int i, j, k;

    int *array = malloc(sizeof(int)*1500000);
    int *temp = malloc(sizeof(int)*10000);

/***** step 1 : find prime numbers *****/

    // initialize array to zero
    for(i=0; i<1500000; i++)
        array[i] = 0;

    // sieve algorithm
    for(i=2; i<1500000; i++)
        if(array[i] == 0){
            j = i;
            k = 0;
            while(k<1500000){
                k = i*j;
                array[k] = 1;
                j = j + 1;
            }
        }
    free(array);
    free(temp);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Replacing:

```
            k = 0;
            while(k<1500000){
                k = i*j;
                array[k] = 1;
                j = j + 1;
            }
```

with:

```
            while(i*j<1500000){
                array[i*j] = 1;
                j = j + 1;
            }
```

doesn't fix all the problems.  Why?

Comment: You're writing past the end of `array` in your `while (k < 1500000)` loop.  First it tests that `k` is in range.  Then it updates `k`.  Then  it immediately uses the *new* value as an index into `array`, without testing to see if the *new* value is in range.  Hint:  Check the value *before* using it as an index.

Comment: Suggest you run your program in a debugger.

Comment: To exclude our suspicion I recommend you check that `k` actually keeps in range, e.g. by using an assert like `k = i*j; assert(k < 1500000); array[k]=1;...`. Also check out `memset()` to initialize your arrays (you don't need a slow loop for that)

Comment: I had while(i**j<1500000) before and it crashed so i thought id try using a third variable.  Can i write array[i***j] = 0? Either way it still crashes, but i'm curious.

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that if you want to allocate an array and initialize its contents to zero, consider using [`calloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc) instead of `malloc()`.

Comment: malloc can return null if it isn't possible to alloc memory

Comment: There are lots of ways you can write this.  You just need to make sure that however you do it, you guarantee that the index you use doesn't exceed the bounds of the array you allocated.  It should be very, very obvious.  How can this possibly be confusing now that it's been pointed out?

Comment: Do not modify a question after you've received answers in such a way as to invalidate the answers.  One of the answers points out a problem in a '`while (k < 1500000)`' loop; it is not kosher to modify the code in the question so that is no longer visible.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
        k = 0;
        while (k<1500000){
            k = i*j;
            array[k] = 1; /* error line */
            j = j + 1;
        }
```

Here the index into the array, k, can be > the sizeof the array and so you get an out of bounds error.

In your code i could be 1499999 and k could also be 1499999.  1499999 * 1499999 = 2249997000001.  In fact the result might overflow too which is probably not what you want.

Always a good idea to step through the code examining the logic.  Programming is like maths - check your logic.

You could also use a debugger to step through your code.  Although in this case that could take a looonnng time!  Or at least you could run in debug mode and it will stop when you get an exception and you can examine variables at that point.

Comment: Hey thank you for explaining that. I changed the code in that loop slightly and yet it still crashes. Could you take another look?

Comment: @bygravity changing from 2 lines: k = i*j; array[k] = 1; to one line: array[i * j] = 1; results in the same logic - think it through.  Also to help other people looking at this, you should not change the question.

Answer (score 0):

It may crash because it can't actually allocate n_bytes for you. Hence you should check the call to malloc :

```
if(array == NULL)
{
puts("ERROR : Can't allocate memory");
return 1;
}
```

Also, if you want your array to be initialized with all 0s values you can use calloc :

```
void *calloc(size_t nitems, size_t size)
```

according to man :

> The calloc() function allocates memory for an array of nmemb
>   elements of size bytes each and returns a pointer to the allo‐
>          cated  memory.   The  memory is set to zero.  If nmemb or size is 0, then calloc() returns either NULL, or a unique pointer
>          value that can later be successfully passed to free().

You can actually do that also with memset function :

```
void *memset(void *str, int c, size_t n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line to use unsigned integers

```
int i, j, k;
```

to this

```
size_t i, j, k;
```

When you multiply signed ints and then compare them you run the risk of the integer being negative ie

```
i = 46349 j = 46349
i*j == -2146737495
```

so your test fails.